# Learning to use expressions in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, references, expression

Is there any resource recommendations in general for getting past the basics of QGIS and going into the deep dark secrets?

Specifically in relation to expression coding for labeling, queries, etc.

Answer (score 9):

Underdark has composed some nice examples for labeling expressions:

[Easier Conditional Labels in QGIS](http://planet.qgis.org/planet/tag/labeling/)

Here are some helpful links for querying:

[Query Attributes](http://maps.cga.harvard.edu/qgis/wkshop/query.php)

[Working with Attribute Table - Basic Queries](http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2010/10/working-with-attribute-table-basic.html)

If you are interested in coding then you can start with this resource:

[pyQGIS Developer Cookbook](http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/)

Answer (score 8):

Some useful stuff here for 1.8 and older

http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/How_do_I_do_that_in_QGIS

http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/quantum-gis/Calculating_field_values

http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/quantum-gis/List_of_Field_Calculator_Functions

Comment: Just note the list of Field Calculator Function is now out of date. All functions that can be used will be listed in the expression builder.

Answer (score 4):

a nice blog with good QGIS tutorials : http://woostuff.wordpress.com/