# How to perform a spatio-temporal query in attribute table?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, select-by-attribute

I am not good at programming, so I would ask for your understanding concerning my question.

I have an attribute table that contains five columns which are: (Date, ID, Latitude, Longitude, Rainfall). 
Rainfall for different periods of time (which are defined in column "Date") have been recorded in certain stations. 
In the column "ID" is the ID of the station on which the recording has been made for a specific period of time.
Every station has a unique ID, but at the same location, rainfall has been recorded for different time periods. On the column "Rainfall" appears the amount of rain that was recorded on the specific time and the specific station.

My question is, how can I get the total rainfall in a certain station that has been recorded, using all the records in column "Date" that refer to that specific station. Could I somehow use the coordinates of its station to get the total rainfall that has occurred on that specific station?

The software I use is QGIS 2.4 on Windows machine.

Comment: Welcome to GIS! Please add which software and version you are using (eg. QGIS 2.4, ArcGIS 10.1 etc)

Comment: As someone new to GIS SE this may give you some quick hints on how to use the various parts of each question you ask: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/how-to-frame-a-good-question/3657#3657  I would recommend that you edit your question to include "I use QGIS 2.4" there rather than as another tag.

Answer (score 0):

Should be a fairly simple query. In Qgis, use select by expression. Under fields and values select the ID field, find the unique ID for the station you would like and you can return all the values for that station. As and example "ID= MissoulaWX". You can add other conditionals to the statement to select for a specific date or range of dates.

Others have asked similar questions here on [GIS.stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45486/idiots-guide-to-expressions-for-qgis)

Comment: F_Kellner, thanks for the response!

The thing is that in my point shapefile I have 2900 stations for which I need to calculate the total rainfall. Is there a way that I can automatise the procedure (calculate the total rainfall for all the stations that have the same ID)?

Comment: I don't have as much experience scripting in Qgis environment, but with Python almost anything is possible. Kicking out the attribute table into a tabular format that you could use in something like Python, or Matlab, or R may make your life easier, rather than trying to script these calculations in Qgis.